# Magento 2 :- How to add product on CMS page

Tags: magento2, product, database, product-attribute, add

I want to add product **url** as button for product **programmatically**. After clicking it should process for purchasing process. I want to add it on CMS or any **custom page**.(exactly how we can add it through

```
admin panel, 

> Page->edit page->add widget(product url link)->save).
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to go very deep in to just add a new block and use button inside anchor tag and then add the product url and insert that block on homepage through widget 
for reference refer the code below:-

```
<a href="http://localhost:96/magento/laptops.html"><button type="button"> Shop Now</button> </a>
```

just do some here in url it is suggested to use dynamic url 
hope this helps

Comment: does it work for you?? or if you need anymore help please let me know

Answer (score 0):

you can call one .phtml file on CSM page or Block and in .phtml file, you can load product and put add to cart button as you want.